# How to refresh a page in wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

How to refresh a page in wp7 i tried this code

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(string.Format(NavigationService.Source +
                                        "?Refresh=true&random={0}", Guid.NewGuid()));
```

but it gives error

```
Navigation is only supported to relative URIs that are fragments, or begin with '/', or which contain ';component/'.
Parameter name: uri
```

So kindly send me the solution as fast as possible.

Comment: -1 Demanding us to send the solution "as fast as possible", no matter how "kindly", should usually involve a monetary transaction.

Comment: What is inside `NavigationService.Source`? As the error message says, if it doesn't begin by '/', it won't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't you put directly the URI of your page? Also, explicitly set your URI as relative. Something like:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(string.Format("/MyPage.xaml?Refresh=true&random={0}", Guid.NewGuid()), UriKind.Relative);
```

Comment: :when i apply this code so my application is abort or close autometically.

Comment: @user1460124 Have you replaced "MyPage.xaml" by the actual name of your page?

Comment: :when i apply this code so my application is abort or close autometically.Actully i have one page in this page one data list is there and this data list contain textblock and this textblock  data came from data base. so what happen when i remove single data into database it will remove successfuly but in data list at a time not remove data so when i press back and than forward so it will show perfectly

Answer (score 0):

**Try the following post from this [forum](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/108580.aspx):**

"It looked like the UriMapper object was not being created against the frame. Adding the UriMapper property to the Frame and pointing it at the resource that sets up the mapping seems to have fixed it. So in page the containing the frame the xaml now looks like ...."

```
<navigation:Frame Grid.Row="1" x:Name="Frame" 
                                  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                  VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                  Padding="0"
                                  Background="White"
                                  JournalOwnership="OwnsJournal"

                                  UriMapper="{StaticResource uriMapper}"    />
```

and in App.xaml application resources I have ....

```
<navigationCore:UriMapper x:Key="uriMapper">
<navigationCore:UriMapping Uri="Contracts" MappedUri="/Views/Contracts.xaml" />
</navigationCore:UriMapper>
```

Comment: Windows Phone and 'desktop' Silverlight are two very different products. As far as I'm concerned, this solution doesn't apply for Windows Phone, the UriMapper is already created per default and maps every single page of the application (actually, I wonder if they aren't just resolved dynamically).

Answer (score -1):

i think KooKiz's method is correct.

i don't know why you get a crash . do you clear your backstack after you new another one?